# Replacing document.write with a jQuery append for script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ads, document.write

I have an advertising script that generates a 300x250 ad unit, and runs like the following:

```
document.write('<scr'+'ipt language="javascript1.1" src="[removed]"></scri'+'pt>');
```

I have to run this script after the page has loaded (on a dialog box) but still in the context of the parent div - I've tried using jQuery to append() both a string and a document.createElement version of this but to no avail. Is there any way to replace this script with a post-load equivalent?

Thanks

Comment: `append` should work, but does the then dynamically loaded script itself use `document.write`?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234896/scripting-adds-with-document-write-vs-jquery-append?rq=1

Comment: why not use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: thanks Bergi, you were right in that the script itself runs document.write - this has led me to actually override the document.write method

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a tip-off from Bergi, I realised the ad script itself was running document.write. The solution (regardless of how horrible it is):

```
            document.write = function(str) {
                $('.ad-container').append(str);
            }
```